# highlight syntax with php by inline styling without javascript for sending mails through php mailer

Tags: php, syntax-highlighting

I need to send some sets of code which user enters through e-mail. The problem is mail's cannot run javascript.. and it uses only inline styles.. so i need to parse the code in php for highlighting and adding it in the mail. Is there any good syntax highlighter to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check these two built in php functions http://php.net/highlight_file and http://php.net/highlight_string

Comment: can it be used for highlighting other lang codes like c or c++ etc.. ?

Comment: no.. sorry, I did not get from the question that it should.. you can see between the comments on php.net some other examples.. also, check it first because most of the keywords are similar to most of the languages and you might be able to use one of these functions..